# Use RSpec let(:foo) across examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using `let(:foo) { create_foo() }` inside my tests. `create_foo` is a test helper that does some fairly time expensive setup.

So everytime a test is run, `foo` is created, and that takes some time. However, the `foo` object itself does not change, I just want to unit test methods on that object, one by one, seperated into single tests.

> So, is there a RSpec equivalent of `let` to share the variable across multiple examples, **but keep the nice things like lazy loading (if `foo` isn't needed) and also the automatic method definition of `foo` so that it can be used in shared examples, without referencing it with a `@foo`?**

Or do I have to simply define a

```
def foo
  create_foo()
end
```

Comment: Since your object gets initialised once at some point in the test suite and does not change, would assigning the result of `create_foo` to a `FOO` constant in some `before(:suite)` configuration allow you to do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just put it in shared examples but use memoization?

```
def foo
  @foo ||= create_foo()
end
```

Comment: I just tested this, when I use it with shared examples, `@foo` gets somehow deleted between my examples

Answer (score 1):

Using `let` in this way goes against what it was designed for. You should consider using `before_all` which runs once per test group:

```
before :all do
  @instancevar = create_object()
end
```

Keep in mind that this may not be wise if create_object() hits a database since it may introduce coupling and maintain state between your tests.

Comment: or `before :suite`